# Cisco VPN is not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I got this error , I dont what is issue ?

```
sudo vpnc
vpnc: Error binding to source port. Try '--local-port 0'
Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:4500: Address already in use
```

On Ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vpnc is sometimes a bit buggy. first, always check whether an instance of vpnc-connect or vpnc is running by doing:

```
ps aux | grep vpnc
```

if there is, kill it with kill and the process id you get on the second column.

i personally always use vpnc-connect instead of a direct call to vpnc (anyway afaik on most system, it's a symlink to vpnc).

could you post your config file? Located under /etc/vpnc/default.conf and /etc/vpnc.conf (remember that you cannot read them as normal user)

regards

Answer (score 1):

the error is because it is trying to use the port that is already in use
you can see that by running

```
netstat -tuvnlp
```

if you specify a different port for it to run it will work fine like

```
 vpnc --local-port=5100 /path/to/vpnfile.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something else is already using port 4500. Try using `netstat` to find out what is going on.

If you want to see Routing Tables, use

```
netstat -nr
```

(`-n` means return numeric output (ie, IP address instead of hostname) and 
`-r` means print the routing table)

To find all open ports, use:

```
netstat -a
```

To find listening ports, use:

```
netstat -l
```

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me;

in my case reason was another vpn client installed (Shrew Soft Ike) and auto-starting at start-up.

Try to catch if some other vpn client is running (in my case, ps -e | grep ike), kill it and configure it to start only when required.